# Moving files on FTP with PowerShell using Rename-FTPItem fails with "(550) File unavailable"

Tags: powershell, ftp, psftp

I need to move files on a remote FTP server from `Test` to `Tested`.  The files are always `.csv`, but the name changes as it's timestamped.  Using the PSFTP module, I have written the following

```
$FtpServer = "ftp://myftpserver.com/"
$User = "myusername"
$PWD = "mypassword"
$Password =  ConvertTo-SecureString $Pwd -AsPlainText -Force

$FtpCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($User, $Password)

Set-FTPConnection -Credentials $FtpCredentials -Server $FtpServer -Session MyFtpSession -UsePassive 

$FtpSession = Get-FTPConnection -Session MyFtpSession

$ServerPath = "ftp://myftpserver.com/Test"
$fileList   = Get-FTPChildItem -Session $FtpSession -Path $ServerPath -Filter *.csv
$archivefolder = "ftp://myftpserver.com/Tested"

foreach ($element in $fileList ) 
{
  $filename = $ServerPath  + $element.name
  $newfilename = $archivefolder  + $element.name

  Rename-FTPItem -Path $filename -NewName $newfilename -Session $FtpSession
}
```

The files do exist in the `Test` folder, but not yet in the archive (`Tested`) folder.  I thought by using a variable to generate what the new file location should be, that would work.

When I try this, I get

> Rename-FTPItem : Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."

Is there a way to move files while using a wildcard, or a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `-NewName` should be a path only, not a URL:

   ```
   $archivefolder = "/Tested"
   ```

   *(In the `-Path`, the URL is acceptable, but it's redundant, you specify the session already using the `$FtpSession`)*
2. You are missing a slash between the folder paths and the file names.

   ```
   $filename = $ServerPath  + "/" + $element.name

   $newfilename = $archivefolder  + "/" + $element.name
   ```

---

So you should call the `Rename-FTPItem` like this:

```
Rename-FTPItem -Path "ftp://myftpserver.com/Test/file.txt" -NewName "/Tested/file.txt" -Session $FtpSession
```

or like this:

```
Rename-FTPItem -Path "/Test/file.txt" -NewName "/Tested/file.txt" -Session $FtpSession
```